# Con't use @Named to resolvable javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: Unresolvable ambiguous bean name detected

Tags: quarkus

```
public interface CommandManager {

     public String start(String id, String command);
    
}

@ApplicationScoped
@Named("foo")
public class CommandManagerImpl implements CommandManager {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public String start(String id, String command){
            //some code
       }
}


@ApplicationScoped
public class OutHandler {

    @Inject
    @Named("foo")
    CommandManager commandManager;
    /**
        .....
        /
}
```

#### Expected behavior

running soomthly

#### Actual behavior

[error]: Build step io.quarkus.arc.deployment.ArcProcessor#generateResources threw an exception: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.DeploymentException: Unresolvable ambiguous bean name detected: foo
CLASS bean [types=[com.lic.thread.CommandManagerImpl, com.lic.thread.commandManager, java.lang.Object], qualifiers=[@Named(value = "foo"), @Default, @Any], target=com.lic.thread.CommandManagerImpl]

Comment: Do you really need `@Named`?

Comment: Do you have and other bean implementing `CommandManager`? Unfortunately, `@Named` doesn't work as a normal qualifier in CDI, so it's best to avoid using it as such.